# Kendo Filter is Not Working on the Date Column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, datepicker, kendo-grid

I have an grid with date column in which I applied a filterable option and i did not get any results when I filter.

My grid:

```
var element = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data: gridDataSource,
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                Date: { type: "date", editable: false },
                            }

                        }

                    }

                },
                scrollable: true,
                filterable : true,

                columns: [
               {
                "field": "Date", "title": "Date", "format": "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", filterable : {ui: function (e) {e.kendoDatePicker({format: "MM/dd/yyyy"})}},  width: "100px" }],

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably is missing `.data("kendoGrid");` in end of `kendogrid()` declaration.

For convinience I did an  [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/2ys5rxck/).

Hope this help

ps: Filter by 1966/01/27 in example to check.

Comment: From Your Example while i removed the .data("kendoGrid"); this code but this is working fine, 

in my code by adding ".data("kendoGrid");" this its not working.

Comment: [This working example](http://jsfiddle.net/2ys5rxck/) is equal to your config, problem can be you data can you show you json ?